# Local storage handling in react in another class

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I had a component that each time something was added to state was added to local storage as well. It was deleted from local storage on componentWillUnmnout. I was told to prepare an indirect abstract layer for local storage handling in order to follow single responsibility principle.
I am confused how this could be done, can someone give an example of such layer, class?

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
    const currUser = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem('currentUser')
    );
    if (
      currUser && nextProps.users.some(
        (user) => user.id === currUser.id
      )
    ) {
      return {
        user: currUser,
      };
    }
    return null;
  }


  const onSelect = (
    user
  ) => {
    this.setState({
      user,
    });
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
  }

  private onRemove = () => {
    this.setState({
      user: null,
    });
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying single responsibility principle here might be over-programming, since Javascripts is not OOP. But if you need, there are some concerns with using `localStorage` directly that can be separated:

- Your component doesn't need to know where you store persistent data. In this case, it doesn't need to know about the usage of localStorage.
- Your component doesn't need to know how you store the data. In this case, it doesn't need to handle `JSON.stringify` to pass to localStorage, and `JSON.parse` to retrieve.

With those ideas, an interface for localStorage can be implemented like so

```
const Storage = {
  isReady: function() {
    return !!window && !!window.localStorage;
  },
  setCurrentUser: function(user) {
    if (!this.isReady()) throw new Error("Cannot find localStorage");
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
    return true;
  },
  getCurrentUser: function() {
    if (!this.isReady()) throw new Error("Cannot find localStorage");
    if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty('currentUser'))
    {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    }
    return null;
  },
  removeCurrentUser: function() {
    if (!this.isReady()) throw new Error("Cannot find localStorage");
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    return true;
  }
}
```

By importing `Storage` object, you can rewrite your component:

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    Storage.removeCurrentUser();
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
    const currUser = Storage.getCurrentUser();
    if (
      currUser && nextProps.users.some(
        (user) => user.id === currUser.id
      )
    ) {
      return {
        user: currUser,
      };
    }
    return null;
  }


  const onSelect = (
    user
  ) => {
    this.setState({
      user,
    });
    Storage.setCurrentUser(user);
  }

  private onRemove = () => {
    this.setState({
      user: null,
    });
    Storage.removeCurrentUser();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks ! And do we need isReady here? When it would happen that we do not have localStorage?

Comment: and also, why is there ` return true;` in setCurrentUser and removeCurrentUser? Does it have to be there? ?;)

Comment: The responsibility of storing data is now on `Storage`, and with that you can replace `localStorage` with something else, e.g. IndexedDB or PouchDB. In that case, `isReady` is necessary for ensure third party plugin is ready to access. The same goes for `return true` since not all DBs ensure 100% success on set/remove data.